# If div is not hidden click anywhere to hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a div hidden by default and show by clicking a button. To close the div, I can either click on the button or anywhere else on the screen. Below is my attempt but the closing part is not working. I appreciated if anyone can point me to the right implementation or maybe a better way to do this.

```
$('#theDiv').hide();

$("#showDivBtn").click(function(){
  $("#theDiv").show();
});

if ( !$('#theDiv:hidden') ) {

$(document).click(function() {
    $('#theDiv').hide();
});
$('#theDiv').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); 
    return false;        
});

}

});
```

Comment: I think you'd best set up a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) which includes some HTML.

Comment: Also, exactly what does "not working" mean?

Comment: well theDiv is hidden on load and I can show it by clicking on 'showDivBtn' but I can't hide it currently. I'll add a jfiddle example.

Comment: You are making a reference to both #theDiv and .theDiv. One of those is wrong I'm guessing?

Comment: yea they should all be id, fixed it. That's not the main issue though.

Comment: So the issue is that theDiv doesn't show because of the click anywhere to hide event is hiding theDiv as I click on the button.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

placing the entire event handler inside a condition only checks the condition on first pageload, and the event handler is probably never attached, try it like this instead :

```
$('#theDiv').hide();

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if ( $(e.target).closest('#showDivBtn').length ) {
        $("#theDiv").show();
    }else if ( ! $(e.target).closest('#theDiv').length ) {
        $('#theDiv').hide();
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/smLPp/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I plugged that in a jsfiddle it appears to have an error, not clear to me why tough. http://jsfiddle.net/smLPp/

Comment: perfect that's what I wanted. thanks!

Comment: @Poyi this won't work in an actual page with content.  You can't click anywhere on the screen to hide the DIV.  You can only click where there aren't any other elements.  This is why you can't listen for a click handler on the `document` element... if there is another element where you click, that element gets the click event, not the `document`.

Comment: @Ghodmode - Sure it will work, events bubble all the way up to the document level, so clicking any element in the document will fire the event handler. This is how delegated event handlers are possible ?

Comment: @adeneo try it.  Your own fiddle doesn't hide the div if you click on either the "Toggle link" div or the div to hide.  Why not?

Comment: @Ghodmode - the point of "clicking anywhere else on the screen", is usually to hide the element if anything **but** the element is clicked, not if the element itself is clicked? The toggle button doesn't toggle the div because it seemed it wasn't supposed to in the OP's code, but if that is in fact what it's supposed to do, one would simply replace `show()` with `toggle()`.

Comment: Awesome code.. working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('#theDiv').hide();

    $("#showDivBtn").click(function(){
      $("#theDiv").toggle();
    });

    $(document).on("click" , function(event){

    if( $(event.target).attr("id") != "theDiv" && $(event.target).attr("id") != "showDivBtn" && $(event.target).parents("#theDiv").attr("id") != "theDiv")
    {
    $('#theDiv').hide();
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

`if( !$('.theDiv' ).is( ':visible' ) )`

instead of

`if ( !$('.theDiv:hidden') )`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.opendiv').hide();
    $(document).click(function (event) {
        var $target = $(event.target);
        if ($target.attr('id') == 'addAccordion') {
            if ($('.opendiv').is(':hidden')) {
                $('.opendiv').show();
            }
            else {
                $('.opendiv').hide();
            }
        }
        else if ($target.closest('.opendiv').length > 0) {

        }
        else {
            $('.opendiv').hide();

        }

    })
</script>
 <div>
    <input id="addAccordion" type="button" value="ADD COMMENT" />
</div>
<div id="rs" class="opendiv">
    <h2>
        Welcome to ASP.NET!
    </h2>
    <p>
        To learn more about ASP.NET visit <a href="http://www.asp.net" title="ASP.NET Website">
            www.asp.net</a>.
    </p>
    <p>
        You can also find <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=152368&amp;clcid=0x409"
            title="MSDN ASP.NET Docs">documentation on ASP.NET at MSDN</a>.
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can target `document` with a `.click` handler like that.

Rather than making it so you can literally click anywhere to close the DIV, just make it seem that way.  Put a clear DIV behind the one that you want to be able to close and make it cover the whole screen.  Then you can attach your click handler to that.

HTML:

```
<button>Click me to show the DIV</button>
<div class="container">
    <div class="thediv">
        <p>I'm the DIV</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $button = $("button");
    var $container = $("div.container");
    $button.click(function () {
        $container.show();
    });
    $container.click(function () {
        $container.hide();
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
div.container {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: -5%;
    left: -5%;
    width: 110%;
    height: 110%;
}
div.thediv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 10%;
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 1em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 50%;
}
p {
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2em;
}
```

For demonstration purposes, I made the background DIV visible in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghodmode/WBwCa/)